# Can まで replace で?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で, particle-まで

Simple question, when まで is used, do I still need to add a で?
I was typing on Google docs, and I wanted to say "the video can end here."

I was going to put `この動画はここまで終われる`, but as you can see in the screenshot below, Google docs is trying to make me add another で. I know that the same sentence can be put as `この動画はここで終われる`, but since I used まで instead of a で, I thought the まで would just replace the で.

In my understanding, `この動画はここで終われる` is `This video can end (at) right here`
`この動画はここまで終われる` is just `This video can end until (or up to) this point`.
As you can see, both ways of saying it make sense in English, and I'd assume no difference in Japanese.

But, if まで is used, do I really need the extra で? Is the suggestion of Google docs correct? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand *This video can end until ....* What exactly do you mean by that？I would have no problem with *This video **cannot** end until ....* if what follows *until* described some condition that allows the video to end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the verbs used, and for 終わる, yes you would need the additional で.

ここまで denotes the whole duration *up to here* and 終わる is something that happens at some point, so simply combining them sounds odd. That is, *to end* was not happening all the time *up to here*, but it happens **at** the end of *up to here*, which is indicated by ここまで**で**.

If the verb is non-instantaneous, you can use ここまで + verb. For example

- 今日はここまでテキストを読んだ Today I read the textbook up to here.

Strictly speaking, I think this should be the same for English *?to end until here*.

---

BTW If you are scripting your own recording, この動画は... is not quite natural. Note that inanimate subjects are less frequent in Japanese in general. It would be natural to say something like この動画をここで終わりにしようと思います or more simply (今回は)ここで終わろうと思います.

Comment: はっきりとわかりました！ありがとうございます